# Not seeing grub after installing Ubuntu alongside windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 10 in dual boot. But after the restart I am not able see the grub and directly starts windows 10. Therefore not able to boot ubuntu or change any other boot settings.

Current bios is UEFI which is default with disabled legacy support.

I searched on internet for solution but everyone says need to modify some grub related file and update the grub. But since ubuntu is not booting I cannot try these methods.

Comment: First, have you tried using the windows bootloader and selecting Ubuntu from the boot options?

Comment: UEFI settings > Boot... Are you sure "Ubuntu" is selected?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI ? How was Ubuntu installed? What method did you use with Windows?

Comment: @mchid how to use windows bootloader? When I turn on laptop it just starts windows normally

Comment: @David bios is in UEFI mode

Comment: @ChanganAuto there is no such settings in my bios. Legacy support is disables by default. When I turn it on I see only legacy first and bios first options

Comment: "Legacy", "BIOS" (and "CSM") are pretty much synonymous in this context. You should be installing in UEFI mode and if you have done that then you'd have the aforementioned choice. Also you can't install a dual-boot with different modes and expect it to work. Any Windows 8 or newer preinstalled is in UEFI mode and so must be Ubuntu in dual-boot.

Comment: You can try to reinstall grub via live-usb. Boot-repair might come in handy for that. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair If this helps you answer here to I can turn it into a answer for any people who has the same issue.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks this one helped and now I am seeing grub when I boot up